# Makefile redirect stderr into a command

Tags: makefile

Using the code below, I am able to redirect the program's standard error output to an error.log file, and call a specific function based on whether or not the program exits peacefully. However in addition to this, I would like to organize the stderr output using the `fold` command, to keep the lines under a max length of 80 characters. How can I achieve this, whilst retaining the current functionality?

Code:

```
define func
    ./myProgram 2> error.log && \
    $(call successCommand)   || \
    $(call failureCommand)
endf
```

Answer (score 0):

This can't work as you have it here.  Make doesn't contain an internal shell interpreter: make invokes a separate shell process.  So, you can't jump back and forth between "shell code" and "make code".

Before make invokes the shell it will expand *all* make variables and functions.  Then once the expansion is complete, the resulting string is passed to the shell and the shell runs the entire thing.  Then once the shell is complete and exits, make looks at the exit code to see if the command succeeded or not.

So in your case, *both* `$(call successCommand)` *and* `$(call failureCommand)` will be expanded **first**, before the shell is invoked to determine whether `./myProgram` succeeded or not.

Since you didn't give us any idea of what the `successCommand` and `failureCommand` do, there's not much help we can give beyond, if the test runs in the shell then the condition AND the results also need to run in the shell, and you can't use make functions like `$(call ...)`.

Comment: Right now, the `successCommand` and `failureCommand` just print "Success!" and "Failed" using the echo command.